# Capitalize strings at given indexes with Swift

Tags: swift, string

I want to be able to capitalizes characters from a string from an array of indexes.

```
let string = "format"
let indexes = [0, 5]
```

```
Expected: "FormaT"
```

Can this be accomplished in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can try and get an array of the characters, and uppercase the ones in your indexes array like this:

```
let string = "format"
let indexes = [0, 5]

var array = string.map{ String($0) }
indexes.forEach{ array[$0] = array[$0].uppercased() }
let fixedString = array.joined()
print(fixedString)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following `String` `extension` should work for you.

```swift
extension String {
    func capitalized(at characters: [Int]) -> String {
        var formattedString = self
        for character in characters {
            formattedString = formattedString.prefix(character) + String(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: character)]).capitalized + formattedString.dropFirst(character + 1)
        }
        return formattedString
    }
}
```

And then using it:

```swift
print("format".capitalized(at: [0,2,5]))
```

Result: `FoRmaT`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `map` through the `String` and at each character, either return the character itself or its uppercased version in case the index of the character is contained in the indices you want to modify.

```
extension String {
    func uppercased(at indices: [Int]) -> String {
        return enumerated().map { indices.contains($0.offset) ? $0.element.uppercased() : String($0.element) }.joined()
    }
}

let string = "format"
let indices = [0, 5]    
print(string.uppercased(at: indices)) // "FormaT"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your indices, get the index at the desired offset and replace the subrange by its uppercase:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func uppercase(at indices: [Int]) {
        for offset in indices {
            let index = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
            replaceSubrange(index...index, with: self[index...index].uppercased())
        }
    }
    func uppercased(at indices: [Int]) -> Self {
        var string = self
        string.uppercase(at: indices)
        return string
    }
}
```

---

```
var string = "format"
let indices = [0, 5]
string.uppercase(at: indices) // "FormaT"
string
print(string.uppercased(at: [1,2])) // "FORmaT\n"
```